# Is there a single word antonym for dissociate?

Tags: solutions, ions, terminology, covalent-compounds

Teaching ionic and covalent compounds, and one of the differences is that some ionic compounds will dissociate when dissolved but covalent compounds usually do not (salt water vs. sugar water, just basic stuff).

Although I'm taking a very basic approach, I would still like to use proper scientific language with my students. **Is there a single-word synonym for "stay bonded" or a single-word antonym for "dissociate"?** My own searches either come up with only 2-word terms or with synonyms for "come together" which aren't appropriate since the atoms are already together before dissolution.

Example sentence: Some ionic compounds dissociate when dissolved, but covalent compounds __ (stay together/don't dissociate) __.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to semantics and not an actual chemistry question

Comment: A proper antonym for dissociate is associate, however, that is not what you are looking for. I do not think that there is a word for what you are describing; I also don't really understand in what way it would be used.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Chemistry vocabulary is off-topic?

Comment: The usual term is dissociate, not disassociate. And I agree with @Martin-マーチン, I cannot think of another term for what you want. I think the clearest and most concise way of putting it would just be "covalent compounds do not dissociate in water". That is a huge generalisation, of course, but may be acceptable for new students.